# How to let Facebook Bots communicate with each other?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

If I myself is owner of both pages, how can they send message to each other? I tried this by sending message to one bot's `access_token` and I got the error:

```
"error":{"message":"(#100) No matching user found","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"Dl170aPSKze"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could connect them on the backend but then you don't need Facebook for that.